# Unable to interact with iFrame through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a page containing an iFrame that loads different website and would like to be able to interact (click, focus, select, enter value etc..) with contents of the iFrame.

So far I am able to check if iFrame has loaded, but once trying to do simple things like hide element in it, nothing happens.

manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my Extension",
  "version": "0.1",

  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*.myPage.com/*",
        "https://*.iframePage.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

content.js

```
console.log('Page Loaded');

var myFrame = $('iframe');

myFrame.ready(function() {
  console.log('Frame Loaded');
});
```

There is also a warning in chrome saying something along the lines:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.iframePage.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.myPage.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Not sure if this is related to issue with extension though.

Comment: I seem to recall you can circumvent cross origin issues in the extension manifest - perhaps look into that

Comment: the warning means: use the same protocol both `http` or `https`.

Comment: Have you looked at setting [all_frames](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and using message passing to communicate with the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Cross Origin Error.

> Cross-origin issues are about the communication between iframes. You
>   can always embed any iframe but, if origin differ, iframes cannot
>   interact with each other.

You cannot access the contents of the iframe.

> The basis of Same Origin Policy is that the window can work in
>   contexts of each other only if they are from same
>   protocol://domain:port,

Refer this [SO Answer-ways to circumvent Cross Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Comment: Ah shame, is there a solution where I can open a new tab instead of using an iFrame and interact with the website that way? Although I am listening to events on my page and need to use them in order to trigger actions on another.

Comment: I dont think you can interact with the website of another domain in any way.

Comment: extensions can (possibly)

Comment: @JaromandaX : It can be possible but I am not sure of the same.

Comment: of course, there is no cross origin issue, as the iframe isn't loading due to protocol issue

Comment: Thankz for showing my mistake @JaromandaX. I have updated the answer.

Comment: you updated it wrong - you fix the protocol issue, THEN it WILL be a cross domain issue